# Remove a comma between two specific characters

Tags: php, regex, string

I currently have the string:

```
"Blah, blah, blah,~Part One, Part Two~,blah blah"
```

I need to remove the comma between the `~` character so it reads.

```
"Blah, blah, blah,~Part One Part Two~,blah blah"
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is exactly one comma between the `~`s and an even number of `~`s in all, then

```
preg_replace("/~([^,]*),([^,]*)~/", "~\1\2~", $text)
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to do this in a few steps:

- Split on `~`
- Transform the parts that are "inside" the `~` only

  - Simply replace `','` with `''`
- Join the parts back together with `~`

---

#### A regex solution

That said, it *is* possible to do this in regex, assuming an even number of `~`:

```
<?php

echo preg_replace(
   '/(^[^~]*~)|([^~]*$)|([^,~]*),|([^,~]*~[^~]*~)/',
   '$1$2$3$4',
   'a,b,c,~d,e,f~,g,h,i,~j,k,l,~m,n,o~,q,r,~s,t,u'
);

?>
```

The above prints ([as seen on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/vsmcBLfD)):

```
a,b,c,~def~,g,h,i,~jkl~m,n,o~qr~s,t,u
```

#### How it works

There are 4 cases:

- We're at the beginning of the string, "outside"

  - Just match until we find the first `~`, so next time we'll be "inside"
  - So, `(^[^~]*~)`
- There are no more `~` till the end of the string

  - If there are even number of `~`, we'll be "outside"
  - Just match until the end
  - So, `([^~]*$)`
- If it's none of the above, we're "inside"

  - Keep finding the next comma before `~` (so we're still "inside")

    - So, `([^,~]*),`
  - If we find `~` instead of a comma, then go out, then go back in on the next `~`

    - So, `([^,~]*~[^~]*~)`

In all case, we make sure we capture enough to reconstruct the string.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Grouping and backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Blah, blah, blah,~Part One, Part Two~,blah blah";
$pos1 = strpos($string, "~");

$substring = substr($string, $strpos, strlen($string));
$pos2 = strpos($string, "~");

$final = substr($substring, $pos1, $pos2);
$replaced = str_replace(",", "", $final);

$newString = str_replace($final, $replaced, $string);
echo $newString;
```

It does the job, but I wrote it right here and might have problems (at least performance problems).

Comment: I'm so glad there are regular expressions.

Comment: True enough! :) I thought regex might be to specific for what he wanted (eg: works on the example but not on the real thing) :)