# string-manipulation - removing char from string

Tags: java, regex, string

I currently have the following string in java:

```
"Blah, blah, blah,~Part One, Part Two~,blah blah"
```

I need to remove the comma between the `~` character so it reads.

```
"Blah, blah, blah,~Part One Part Two~,blah blah"
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Many thanks,

Comment: Is there a specific number of times the ~ appears in the string? Will it always be twice or any even number of times?

Comment: They always encapsulate a string, so always in pairs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    String[] tests = {
        "a,b,c,d,e,f",
        "a,b,~c~,d,e",
        "~a,b,c,d,e~",
        "a,b,c,~d,e,f~,g,h,i,~j,k,l,~m,n,o~,q,r,~s,t,u",
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println(
            test.replaceAll(
                "(^[^~]*~)|([^~]*$)|([^,~]*),|([^,~]*~[^~]*~)",
                "$1$2$3$4"
            )
        );
    }
```

The above prints:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,~c~,d,e
~abcde~
a,b,c,~def~,g,h,i,~jkl~m,n,o~qr~s,t,u
```

#### How it works

There are 4 cases:

- We're at the beginning of the string, "outside"

  - Just match until we find the first `~`, so next time we'll be "inside"
  - So, `(^[^~]*~)`
- There are no more `~` till the end of the string

  - If there are even number of `~`, we'll be "outside"
  - Just match until the end
  - So, `([^~]*$)`
- If it's none of the above, we're "inside"

  - Keep finding the next comma before `~` (so we're still "inside")

    - So, `([^,~]*),` (don't capture the comma!)
  - If we find `~` instead of a comma, then go out, then go back in on the next `~`

    - So, `([^,~]*~[^~]*~)`

In all cases, we make sure we capture enough to reconstruct the string.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Grouping and backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

#### Related questions

- [Remove a comma between two specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118169/remove-a-comma-between-two-specific-characters) (PHP version)

Comment: chapeau, in 24min. I give way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I would do something like:

```
string sample = "Blah, blah, blah,~Part One, Part Two~,blah blah";
Regex r = new Regex("(.+)\\~(.+),(.+)\\~(.+)","${1}~${2}${3}~${4}");
r.replaceAll(sample );
```

I referenced [Regular Expressions in Java](http://www.javaregex.com/tutorial5.html). In here the .+ matches to one or more any character. More such patterns can be found [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "Blah, blah, blah,~Part One, Part Two~,blah blah,~Part One, Part Two~,blah blah";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("~[^~]+~");
Matcher matcher =pattern.matcher(text);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group(0).replaceAll(",", ""));
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
text = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that would do the job:

```
public String deleteCharacterBetween(String deleteFrom, String betweenChar, String charToRemove) {
    int nextIndex = 0, index = 0;
    while (true) {
        index = deleteFrom.indexOf(betweenChar, nextIndex);
        nextIndex= deleteFrom.indexOf(betweenChar, index + 1);
        if (nextIndex < 0 || index < 0)
            return deleteFrom;
        String before = deleteFrom.substring(0, index);
        String toEdit = deleteFrom.substring(index, nextIndex);
        String after = deleteFrom.substring(nextIndex);
        toEdit = toEdit.replace(charToRemove, "");
        deleteFrom = before + toEdit + after;
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
String a = "Blah, blah, blah,~Part One, Part Two~,blah blahBlah, blah, blah,~Part One, Part Two~,blah blah";
System.out.println(deleteCharacterBetween(a, "~", ","));
```